# Angular Fallback Image With Status Code

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to get a fallback image working that behaves differently based on the status code.  My images are coming out of SharePoint and in certain (Microsoft) browsers I have to request the images through a Web API so that I can append the proper authentication cookies.

I already have a fallback working that if an image fails it requests the image through the Web API and gets the Base64 representation.  The problem is there's no point doing this if the image isn't there.  So if it's a 404 I'd like to just display the placeholder, but if it's a 302 I'll get the image a different way.

Checking the error object and all the fallback directives I can find, I can't see a way to find out the error code.

Thanks!